# How to make the Asus USB-AC55R to work with Ubuntu 18.04 or Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: wireless, 18.04, games, asus, 19.04

My motherboard is a Gigabyte ga-970a-dsp. I don't have access to any ethernet ports so I will have to use wifi. I have a separate Windows 10 computer that I can use to help with stuff such as downloading. Hoping to eventually use my system for gaming.

Here's the output of lsusb: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hIwq.jpg

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of  `lsusb`  with the Asus dongle connected (only the line pertaining to the wireless adapter is relevant).

Comment: you are not stating the problem ... did you run the install yet ?

Comment: output provided. I just have the live usb running at the moment.

Comment: Please do not post screenshots for that. Instead copy the relevant line (as I told you) and post it as code (click {} and paste inside). That said, it shows the chipset is Mediatek MT7612U so this might work: https://askubuntu.com/a/1119028/880592